# == operator is not giving true even when strings are same

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my code:

```
$param = $old_password.$salt;
$hashed_password = $this->general->hash($param);
//echo $hashed_password;echo " "; echo $userdata->password;exit;
if($hashed_password == $userdata->password){
    print_r("com");exit;
}
print_r("didn't match");exit;
```

when I echo as above result is

```
8fb9ccf75da3c0eb285d3dddd80895a8f15f64d5 8fb9ccf75da3c0eb285d3dddd80895a8f15f64d5
```

which is exactly same. But it doesn't enters into the if statement.

Comment: have you tried with the equals() methed ?

Comment: trim the strings before compare.

Comment: You are using wrong way to compare string. You need to compare string using `strcmp()` function, check my answer.

Comment: Try with "===" is more accurate

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump()` on both variables. Maybe you have empty spaces somewhere.

Comment: And if that doesn't solve your problem either try using the "===" operator

Comment: Yeah, there is one extra space on th data that came from database. How would that come?

Comment: It depends on the database,but sometimes strings get reformated to have a certain length.

Comment: This is not fair because I can not comment and I knew how to help him,but whatever...keep it up ;)

Comment: Anyway your suggestion help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Compare string using `strcmp()` function

```
$param = $old_password.$salt;
$hashed_password = $this->general->hash($param);
if (strcmp($hashed_password, $userdata->password) == 0) {
    echo "matched"; exit;
}else{
    echo "didn't match"; exit;
}
```

Refrence : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
         // $param=$old_password.$salt;
         $hashed_password = $this->general->hash($param);
         $password = $userdata->password;
         //echo $hashed_password;echo " "; echo $userdata->password;exit;
         if($hashed_password == $password)
         {
          print_r("com");exit;
         }else
         {
            print_r("didn't match");exit;   
         }
```